# In Mulesoft DWL how to map payload with loop till we have null in the loop

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

Hi I have a json payload in which we have loop which is like below.

```
{
   "ABC":[
      {
         "BCD":[
            {
               "ABC":[
                  {
                     "BCD":[
                        {
                           "ABC":[
                              {
                                 "BCD":[]-> Repeats till we get null
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

above loop will continue till we get null value which will vary for different payload. Is their a way we can give the logic like the loop should continue till we have the null value My output is expected to be in XML

Comment: Always add a sample input , expected output and if you have tried with any approach this far.

Comment: Hi @Sumanth Reddy. As Salim says, it's important to have the output you want to achieve in this case becasue the solution can vary. For example, just using `output application/xml --- payload` will provide a proper XML, but not sure if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little trick to emulate do-while in datawave scripts.

indicate end of iterations (to emulate while).
Simplest way is to use value as accumulator and sign as indicator. While accumulating summary value negative result indicates end of cycles.

```
%dw 2.0
var x=[1,2,3,4,5]
output application/json
---
-(x reduce (item, acc=0) -> if (item <4 and acc >= 0) acc + item else if (acc>0) -acc else acc)
```

Some complex object could be used to collect results and also have indicator of the end of cycle as part of the object

```
%dw 2.0
var x=[1,2,3,4,5]
output application/json
---
(x reduce (item, acc={sum:0}) -> if (item < 4 and acc.end==null ) (acc - 'sum' ++ {sum: acc.sum+item}) else ( acc ++ {end:true} )).sum
```

Use your condition (like null) to terminate your loop.

https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/DoWhileImitation.html